# Clear search after form submit

Tags: javascript, html

I would like the search bar to be cleared after the user presses the search button. Is there a quick workaround that is not invasive?

```
<form method="POST" id="Submit">
              <div class="inner-form">
                <div class="input-field first-wrap">
                  <input id="search" name="input" placeholder="Paste here" type="text" required oninvalid="onInvalid(event)" />
                </div>
            
                <div class="input-field second-wrap">
                  <button id="button" class="btn-search" onclick="searchIt()" value="press" type="submit">
                      SEARCH
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p class="errorMessage" id="errorMessage"></p>
            </form>
```

Comment: `document.forms.Submit.reset()`

Comment: `document.getElementById('Submit').reset()`

Comment: @zer00ne how should integrate into current code?

Comment: @kemicofaghost how should integrate into current code?

Comment: @KirkCode see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73005908/2813224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the submit event to the `<form>`:

```
document.forms.Submit.onsubmit = e => /* ... */
```

then call the `.reset()` method on the `<form>` via `e.target`, also wrap it in a `setTimeout()`:

```
/* ... */ setTimeout(() => e.target.reset(), 0)
```

I have the `<form>` sending data to a live test server and an `<iframe>` to display the response so you can see that after a search the `<input>` is cleared.

```html
<form action='https://httpbin.org/post' method="POST" id="Submit" target='response'>
  <div class="inner-form">
    <div class="input-field first-wrap">
      <input id="search" name="input" placeholder="Paste here" type="text" required oninvalid="onInvalid(event)" />
    </div>

    <div class="input-field second-wrap">
      <button name='btn' class="btn-search" value="press" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="errorMessage" id="errorMessage"></p>
</form>
<iframe name='response'></iframe>
<script>
document.forms.Submit.onsubmit = e => setTimeout(() => e.target.reset(), 0);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the text on input search.

```js
function searchIt(){
  document.getElementById('search').value="";
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="Submit">
  <div class="inner-form">
    <div class="input-field first-wrap">
      <input id="search" name="input" placeholder="Paste here" type="text" required oninvalid="onInvalid(event)" />
    </div>

    <div class="input-field second-wrap">
      <button id="button" class="btn-search" onclick="searchIt()" value="press" type="submit">
          SEARCH
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="errorMessage" id="errorMessage"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: How does this solve my problem?

Comment: Instead of the form, you should use the javascript functions and clean the input simply

Answer (score 0):

```js
function searchIt(e){

e.preventDefault();
/* do what you want
   submit form
*/

document.getElementById('Submit').reset()
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="Submit">
  <div class="inner-form">
    <div class="input-field first-wrap">
      <input id="search" name="input" placeholder="Paste here" type="text" required oninvalid="onInvalid(event)" />
    </div>

    <div class="input-field second-wrap">
      <button id="button" class="btn-search" onclick="searchIt(event)" value="press" type="submit">
                      SEARCH
                  </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="errorMessage" id="errorMessage"></p>
</form>
```